# Another Quicksort stackoverflow

Tags: c#, quicksort, stack-overflow

So I've been trying to implement a quicksort myself, just to learn something from it, but it also generates a stackoverflowexception, but I can't seem to find what the cause is.

Can someone give me a clue?

```
  public void Partition(List<int> valuelist, out List<int> greater, out List<int> lesser)
        {
            lesser = new List<int>();  // <-- Stackoverflow exception here!
            greater = new List<int>();

            if (valuelist.Count <= 1)
                return;

            pivot = valuelist.First();

            foreach (int Element in valuelist)
            {
                if (Element <= pivot)
                    lesser.Add(Element);
                else
                    greater.Add(Element);
            }
        }

        public List<int> DoQuickSort(List<int> list)
        {
            List<int> great;
            List<int> less;

            Partition(list, out great, out less);

            DoQuickSort(great);
            DoQuickSort(less);

            list.Clear();
            list = (List<int>)less.Concat(great);

            return list;

        }
```

Comment: isn't this best to find by just giving it some small data to sort, and step with the debugger through it to see where the logic is incorrect?

Comment: I don't think any sort algorithm that relies on creating lots of collections and copying lots of values can be called "quick".  You should rename it "memory-intensive slogsort guaranteed to be slow as possible."

Comment: @reinier: Relying on the debugger to find your logic errors is pretty lazy. Sometimes it's unavoidable, but it's far better to be able to find the errors without the help of a debugger.

Comment: @Will thanks for pointing that out, I'm trying to learn something here, not doing algorithm optimization.

Comment: @Tony best thing to do is partition the INDEX of your collection.  Switching the position of two elements within a collection is a bit faster than creating two new collections and copying values into it.  Good luck with the algorithm learning; I bought Knuth's treatise on algorithms and about jumped off the roof after reading the first couple chapters.

Comment: zakalwe: relying on others to find it on stackoverflow is one step lazier ;^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not putting any conditions on your recursive calls to `DoQuicksort`, so it'll never stop recursing, leading to a stack overflow. You should only be calling `DoQuicksort` on a list if it contains more than one element.

**Edit:** As Will said in his comment, this is a very slow approach to "Quicksort". You should look at in-place partitioning algorithms, as mentioned on Wikipedia's [Quicksort article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

Answer (score 5):

you are doing an infinite loop right there

```
  DoQuickSort(great);
```

you need a way to get out of that loop with a flag or a condition

**Edit**
I will add that in debugging mode, with default setting, you can only reach between 10,000 and 16,000 recursive call before an exception is thrown and between 50,000 and 80,000 when in release mode, all depend on the actual code executed.

If you play with a huge number of values, you might need to manage yourself that recursive call by using a [Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx) object.

sample code to see how much call before it crash;
(debug; 14,210 call, release 80,071 call)

```
   static int s = 1;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        o();
    }

    static void o()
    {
        s++;
        Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
        o();
    }
```

Comment: Right - because the pivot is put as the first entry in `great`, so you'll end using the same pivot every time.

Comment: Yeah, there isn't any condition checking in the DoQuickSort method.  The Partition method is smart enough to know when to quit, but that kind of check isn't being done in the caller.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the problems in your code that you keep the pivot value when partitioning the list. This means that you will run into a situation where all values partition into either greater or less, and the partitioning will stop working. This will effectively not letting you split one of the lists anylonger, so the exit condition in the Partition method is never satisfied.

You should select a pivot value, *remove the pivot element from the list* (this part is missing in your code), parition it in greater and less lists, sort those (recursively), and then concatenate the less list, the pivot element (this is also, naturally, missing in your code) and the greater list.

I can post an updated, working, code sample, but since you are in "learning mode", I will keep it to myself until you ask for it :)

Comment: Do I remove a new pivot value each time going through it? and add it again in it's right place @ the end of the partition?  Confused?!?

Comment: @Tony: I think that the pseudocode samples in the Wikipedia article may straighten it out for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm